# JavaScript getElementById always returning null

Tags: javascript, html, document, getelementbyid

I am trying to build a simple budget calculator, everytime I click my submit button I nothing happens. When I try to check my variable values in the console they show null, even after I have typed values in my input boxes. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? After looking through other questions on here I haven't been able to find an answer that relates to my issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Budget Calculator</title>
    <style>
        input {display:block;}
        #clear {float:left;}
        #submit {float:left;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var kms = document.getElementById("kmTravelled");
        var rent = document.getElementById("rentPerMonth");
        var carCost = document.getElementById("carPayment");
        var costPerTrip = (kms/12.75)*20;
        var total = Math.round((costPerTrip + rent + carCost)*100)/100;

        function calculate()
        {
            document.getElementById("calculator").innerHTML = total;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>


    <form id="myForm")>
        Km travelled per day: <input type="number" name="kmTravelled" />
        Rent per month: <input type="number" name="rentPerMonth" />
        Car payment per month: <input type="number" name="carPayment" />
    </form>
    <button id="submit" type="button" onclick="calculate();">
        Submit
    </button>
    <button id="clear" type="clear">
        Clear
    </button>

    <p id = "calculator">
    </p>

    <script>
        calculate();
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: just a small hint: `<form id="myForm")>` you have a closing parenthesis to much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use `id` attributes and move the parts for getting the values inside of the function, as well as getting `value` property and cast the string value to number for calculation.

```js
function calculate() {
    var kms = +document.getElementById("kmTravelled").value;
    var rent = +document.getElementById("rentPerMonth").value;
    var carCost = +document.getElementById("carPayment").value;
    var costPerTrip = (kms / 12.75) * 20;
    var total = Math.round((costPerTrip + rent + carCost) * 100) / 100;

  document.getElementById("calculator").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```css
input { display: block; }
#clear { float: left; }
#submit { float: left; }
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  Km travelled per day: <input type="number" name="kmTravelled" id="kmTravelled"/> Rent per month: <input type="number" name="rentPerMonth" id="rentPerMonth" /> Car payment per month: <input type="number" name="carPayment" id="carPayment" />
</form>
<button id="submit" type="button" onclick="calculate();">Submit</button>
<button id="clear" type="clear">Clear</button>
<p id="calculator"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have no `id`'s in you `input`'s but you have `name`'s instead so you could use name selector `$('[name=""]')` like :

```
var kms = document.querySelector("[name='kmTravelled']").value;
var rent = document.querySelector("[name='rentPerMonth']").value;
var carCost = document.querySelector("[name='carPayment']").value;
```

If you want really to use `id`'s , just add them and the JS code could be :

```
var kms = document.querySelector("#kmTravelled").value;
var rent = document.querySelector("#rentPerMonth").value;
var carCost = document.querySelector("#carPayment").value;
```

**NOTE :** You should get just the `value` of the element not the whole object.

Hope this helps.

```js
var kms = document.querySelector("[name='kmTravelled']").value;
var rent = document.querySelector("[name='rentPerMonth']").value;
var carCost = document.querySelector("[name='carPayment']").value;
var costPerTrip = (kms/12.75)*20;
var total = Math.round((costPerTrip + rent + carCost)*100)/100;

function calculate()
{
  document.getElementById("calculator").innerHTML = total;
}

calculate();
```

```css
input {
  display:block;
}

#clear {
  float:left;
}

#submit {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm")>
    Km travelled per day: <input type="number" name="kmTravelled" />
    Rent per month: <input type="number" name="rentPerMonth" />
    Car payment per month: <input type="number" name="carPayment" />
</form>

<button id="submit" type="button" onclick="calculate();">
    Submit
</button>

<button id="clear" type="clear">
    Clear
</button>

<p id = "calculator"></p>
```

Comment: This would still break as the elements don't exist when the script caching the elements runs.

Comment: That actually helped. I'm not this basic at js, just made a simple mistake in putting name instead of id. '-_- Thanks for pointing out my error!

Comment: Check my update please. No worries @RegSmith have happen to all of us ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try getElementById('kmTravelled').

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to give proper id in HTML tag. check your HTML tag, convert those **name** into **id**. 
Now you have to slightly change your *javascript code*, if you look at your code **you didn't assign any value to your variable**. fix these problems and your code will run properly.